# How to copy a local folder to Subclipse / Eclipse folder structure?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Can I drag&drop a folder from my home folder that has many subdirs and even .svn subdirs into my Navigator view in my subclipsed Ecplipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by trying - Yes you can. You have to right click on the new folder and choose "add to version control".

If you have folders / subfolders however that contain an old .svn folder, you have that folder remove from eclipse again, commit and copy over again.

Alternatively, just recreate the folders / subfolders by hand in eclipse and drag&drop the files over

Either way you will loose Version Control of the old files. If you want to keep Version Control you have to use the SVNAdmin tool to do the migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with files that are in a Subversion repository, why not check them out again from Eclipse?